# Compare two websites final out put per page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I have been tasked with writing a test tool to take a web page and compare it to the same page after we change our skin to detect changes.

I need to detect if things have changed positions like text or input fields etc.

We are primarily a .Net shop and all of our sites our in ASP.Net. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways:

1. compare html sources (probably not enough)
2. compare two screenshot pixel by pixel :) and return third screen with marked differences

Comment: Thanks I think I am going to do screen shots and use ImageMagick to compare for me.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).  It sounds like it might be a good tool for the job.  If you are asking for code to do this then your question isn't really appropriate for this site.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: The code I can do just a helpful nudge in the right direction is what I needed.

Comment: There is no good code answer to this IMHO.  If there is a tool for the job, then I would argue that naming that tool is an answer.